# Error in AG Grid when using valueGetter when defining ColumnDefs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

First time writing here so apologies if I'm not doing it correctly.
I am trying change the value type of a string into an integer when importing values into my AG Grid in React. In order to do this, I created this column header :

```
 {
    headerName: "calc inline clicks",
    field: "adsetstats_inline_link_clicks",
    aggFunc: "sum",
    valueGetter: params => {
        return parseInt(params.data.adsetstats_inline_link_clicks_0days_ago);
    }
  }
```

I then run:

```
this.setState({ rowData })
```

However, when I run this, React gives me the following error:

> Error: ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.

Any idea how to fix this? Nothing I have done seems to work.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: can you provide stackblitz or plinkr sample, it would be much simpler to help your then.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue too. The real problem is that the `valueGetter` is throwing an error, but for some reason that error is swallowed and ag-grid displays this error instead. In your case, you may want to check that `params.data` is defined before accessing its property.

Comment: I ran into this with a custom cellClassRules function that would occasionally get bad data. When I put a try/catch around the function, I could see the error, but otherwise it was completely swallowed up by ag-grid

Answer (score -1):

Use SetTimeout() around the this.setState and put timeout for 100ms. It works

Comment: It's wrong approach, even if it works you shouldn't use it, cuz you can lack your life-circle and then it could bring more complex issues.